# How to move prestashop development version from localhost to server?

Tags: php, node.js, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have a question how can i move my prestashop 1.7.8.0 version from localhost to server without local environments (like node_modules). I want to move the files to the server but without node_modules folders and how can I do this fast without manually remove unwanted folders?

Comment: i suggest you to install Prestashop on production server from official ZIP repo, then sync only your customized folders (like /modules - /themes - /img and , of course, the DB) - or just use an rsync approach with an exclude-list (you can use the .gitignore file as source for files to be exclude)

Comment: There is no better and faster way to do this with .gitignore that provides required files for prestashop? Without install first "official ZIP repo"?

Comment: it's always matter of excluding folders and synchronizing what's left. I can't figure out how could you do it faster than that.